# MoveRight method not working

Tags: perl, perl-module, win32ole

I want to select a word character by character unless a space is encountered. I am getting an error as "Can't call method "MoveRight" without a package or object reference". Please help me.
Thanks in advance.
Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings; 
use Win32::OLE qw(in); 
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';

my $selection;

my $word = new Win32::OLE 'Word.Application','' or die "Cannot start
word!\n";

$word->{visible}=0;  

my $doc = $word->Documents->Open( 'C:\\PerlScripts\\myTest.docx' );

$selection = $word->Selection;

$selection->Find->{Text} = "hi";

$selection->Find->{Forward} = 'true';

$selection->Find->{MatchWildcards} = 'true';

$selection->Find->{MatchPrefix} = 'true';

if ( $selection->Find->Execute ) {
print "The search text was found\n";
while($selection->Next ne " ")
{
    $selection = $selection->MoveRight({Unit => wdCharacter, Count => 1, Extend => wdExtend}) ;
}   
print $selection->{Text};
} else {       
print "The search text was not found\n";
}
```